# Composing a mail from Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm a learner, i'm trying to compose a mail from new gmail, but not able to enter id's in to list after compose window opens,tried switching the frame method but was not successfull in locating the to field itself, can you please help me in this.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to show us what you have tried so we can point you in the right direction. Be aware though, gmail is hard to use with Webdriver, I'm fairly sure its been created in a way that makes it hard to automate.

Answer (score 0):

This blog contains a lot of examples that are doing just that:

http://shilpamynampati.blogspot.com/

Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of composing a mail from GMail account.

```
package testCase;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class GmailFileUpload 
{
    WebDriver driver = null;
    WebElement element = null;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception 
    {
        File file = new File("G:\\Selenium\\All_Jars\\chromedriver.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException, AWTException 
    {
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("aavinashpande@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("your gmail password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Gmail")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'COMPOSE')]")).click(); //Click on Compose button
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@name='to']")).sendKeys("aavinashpande@gmail.com"); // write mail id to whom do you want to send an email
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='subjectbox']")).sendKeys("want to say Hello"); // write subject
        element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='Ar Au']//div"));
        element.click();
        element.sendKeys("Hi Avinash"); //type in message body
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Send')]")).click(); //click on send button
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package basic;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class mozilaProj {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String path = "D:\\harsh\\Selenium data\\geckodriver.exe";  //location where your driver is placed.
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", path);  
        WebDriver wd=new FirefoxDriver();
        wd.navigate().to("http://accounts.google.com");

        wd.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("Your mail ID");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/content/span")).click();  // Click on next 
        Thread.sleep(4000);  //wait needed here To get the password page.
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/content/section/div/content/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("Email Password");  // click on next
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/content")).click();  //If your page redirect to google security page.
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        wd.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gb_mf > path:nth-child(1)")).click(); //click on google apps tab. 
        wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("#gb23 > span:nth-child(5)")).click();  //click on gmail icon.
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div")).click();   // click on compose  

         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wd, 20);   // implement wait here to load all data.
        wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("to")));
        wd.findElement(By.name("to")).sendKeys("recepient mail ID");
        wd.findElement(By.id(":mx")).sendKeys("Subject of mail");
        wd.findElement(By.id(":o0")).sendKeys("Mail body "); // type mail body 
        wd.findElement(By.id(":mn")).click();    // Send button click
        Thread.sleep(8000);  // Apply wait for sending mail 
        wd.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Please add comments in the code or describe to help others understand.